# Maintaining reference to UITextField "text" field

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, pass-by-pointer

**Problem:**

I am trying to create a custom UITextField class "UIValidatedTextField" which allows one to set certain rules as to whether input is valid. For example, you can set a regex parameter to ensure that input is of a specific format, i.e. a password, email address, etc...

Another ability of this is to specify and set a parameter that references another UITextField and ensures that the input matches the input from that other UITextField.

The issue I am having here, is that I am setting this reference to another UITextField. However, when I access its "text" field I find that there is nothing in the text field even when I type something into it.

I have provided related code below:

```
#import "UIRegisterViewController.h"
#import "UIRegisterViewCell.h"
#import "UIValidatedTextField.h"
#import "NSConstants.h"

@interface UIRegisterViewController ()


@end

@implementation UIRegisterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableItems = @[@"name", @"email", @"netId", @"username", @"password", @"confirmPassword"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_tableItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [_tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIRegisterViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"email"]) {
        [cell.textField setRegex:VALID_DUKE_EMAIL_REGEX];

    } else if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"netId"]) {
        //Validation?

    } else if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"username"]) {
        //Validation?

    //THIS IS THE CELL THAT I WANT TO COMPARE INPUT TO
    } else if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"password"]) {
        [cell.textField setRegex:VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX];

    //SETTING THE TEXT FIELD IN QUESTION HERE...
    } else if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"confirmPassword"]) {
        [cell.textField setRegex:VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX];
        NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
        UIRegisterViewCell *confirm =(UIRegisterViewCell *)[self tableView:_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
        [cell.textField setConfirm:confirm.textField];
    }

    cell.textField.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Text Field Delegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


@end
```

Note that the textFields are UIValidatedTextFields - a custom class provided below:

```
    #import "UIValidatedTextField.h"
#import "NSArgumentValidator.h"

@implementation UIValidatedTextField

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initialize {
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
                name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:self];
        [self validate]; //Validate in case editing began before observer was set.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setOptional:(BOOL)isOptional {
    _isOptional = isOptional;
}

- (BOOL) isOptional {
    return _isOptional;
}

- (void) setRegex:(NSString *)regex {
    _regex = regex;
}

//SET THE TEXT FIELD TO COMPARE INPUT AGAINST HERE.
- (void) setConfirm:(UITextField *)confirm {
    _confirm = confirm;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
            name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:_confirm];
    [self validate]; //Validate in case editing on confirm began before observer was set.
}

- (void) setQuery:(NSString *)query {
    _query = query;
}

- (void) textFieldDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"UPDATE");
    _isValid = [self validate];
    [self showInputValidation];
}

- (BOOL) validateRegex {
    if (_regex.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return [NSArgumentValidator isValid:self.text withRegex:_regex];
}

- (BOOL) validateConfirm {
   // NSLog(@"%@ : %@", [_confirm text], self.text);
    if (_confirm == NULL) {
        //NSLog(@"IS NULL");
        return true;
    }
    return [self.text isEqualToString:_confirm.text];
}

- (BOOL) validateQuery {
    return true;
}

- (BOOL) validate {
    _isValid = (self.text == 0 && _isOptional) || ((self.text != 0) && [self validateRegex] && [self validateConfirm] && [self validateQuery]);
    return _isValid;
}

//IF ANYONE HAS A SOLUTION AS TO HOW TO MAKE CHANGING BORDER COLOR CHANGE THE COLOR ALONG THE ROUNDED BORDER THAT IS PRESENT AS OPPOSED TO A RECTANGULAR BORDER LET ME KNOW.
- (void) showInputValidation {
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    if (self.text.length == 0) {
        self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    } else if (_isValid) {
        self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
    } else {
        self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    }
}
- (void) finalize {
    [super finalize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
            name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:self];

    if (_confirm != NULL) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:_confirm];
    }
}

@end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One glaring bug in this code is that you're setting the regex in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, even though all cell are reusing the same cell object. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should be used only to set cell content, like text and color. Instead, create an `IBOutlet` to the validating text fields and add their regexes in `viewDidLoad`. Better yet, scrap the custom subclass entirely and instead run your regex validation whenever one of the relevant text fields fires off an event when editing is finished.

Comment: Each cell dequeued is different and has a different identifier. I'm sure I could fix it that way, albeit very messily, but I'd also like to understand why this does not work the way it is.

Comment: It's because reusable cells are used like rubber stamps for drawing cells, not for handling the business logic behind cells. I don't know for sure, but my guess is that when you set the regex in one call to `dequeue`, it gets clobbered, or the text to be checked gets clobbered, on the next `dequeue` call.

Comment: I think I see now, so essentially when you call that method it is recreating the cell at the specified index rather than retrieving the actual cell that is being displayed - or do I misunderstand? Is there anyway to retrieve the actual cell?

Comment: Awesome, well thanks. I managed to fix it by changing the table view to have static cells and linking them all to IBOutlets. I then just set the confirm parameter of the text field in question by referencing the cell IBOutlet with the text field that I want to confirm against. Thanks for the help!